# trying to understand what this regex means

Tags: regex

Trying to understand what the below regex means.

> /^[0-9]{2,3}[- ]{0,1}[0-9]{3}[- ]{0,1}[0-9]{3}$/

Sorry not exactly a coding question.

Comment: Means the same as this `^\d{2,3}(?:[- ]?\d{3}){2}$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this regex into a few different parts:

- `^`: asserts position at start of the string
- `[0-9]{2,3}`: Match a number between 0 and 9, between 2 and 3 times
- `[- ]{0,1}` Matches a dash between zero and one times (Optional dash)
- `[0-9]{3}`: Match a number between 0 and 9, exactly 3 times
- `[- ]{0,1}` Matches a dash between zero and one times (Optional dash)
- `[0-9]{3}`: Match a number between 0 and 9, exactly 3 times
- `$`: asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)

Here are a few strings that would pass this regex:

- `123-123-123`
- `123123123`
- `12-123-123`
- `12123123`

Here's a good resource to learn/test regexes: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It matches two or three digits followed by (optionally) a dash or space, then 3 digits, again optional dash or space and 3 digits. It seems to try to match a telephone number written in different formats.